# ASP.NET Identity Manager to manage page level user access

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, identityserver3

Now that I can use ASP.NET Identity Manager to manage the users and Roles. By the way, I am doing it in web form at the moment.

Next what I want to learn is what will be a good way to manage the page based on Roles. Means example **Admin Role** can access to page1.aspx and page2.aspx while **User Role** can access to only page3.aspx.

Write my own custom code or there is a Microsoft built-in class to do this?

Regards, Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Web Forms and MVC you can add the Authorize attribute to the class or each method for to implement role based permissions on a per page basis.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "User,Admin")]
```

If you need to go beyond that you will need to build your own code to suit your needs.

Comment: any sample i can refer to ?